# NHibernate 3.0 IQueryable selecting ghost column

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I'm getting a strange error when running what appears to be a simple query.

```
return (from x in session.Query<Contact>()
                .Where(x => x.Id == 10)
               select new ContactIndexViewModel
               {
                   Id = x.Id,
                   Name = x.BasicInfo.FirstName + " " + x.BasicInfo.LastName,
                   Filters = x.Filters
               }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is generating the following SQL

```
select 
    contact0_.[Id] as col_0_0_, 
    contact0_.[BasicInfoFirstName] as col_1_0_, 
    contact0_.[BasicInfoLastName] as col_2_0_, 
    . as col_3_0_,
    filters1_.[Id] as column1_16_, 
    filters1_.Criteria1 as Criteria2_16_, 
    // .. .more filters1_ fields
    filters1_.ContactId as ContactId16_ 
from 
    [MyServer].[dbo].[Contact] contact0_ 
    inner join [MyServer].[dbo].[Filter] filters1_ 
        on contact0_.[Id]=filters1_.ContactId
where
    contact0_.[Id]=@p0
```

**Notice the fourth column being selected**. BasicInfo is a component and the select (in the query) includes all the fields defined in the ViewModel.

I am not having any other problems with the Contact or Filter objects in other parts of the application. Contact -> Filter has a one to many relationship.

Any idea's on how to debug or what may cause this?

**UPDATE**

If I remove the reference to Filters in the `select`, the problem goes away.

**UPDATE** Relevant Mappings

Contact

```
public partial class ContactMap : ClassMap<Contact>
{
    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ContactMap"/> class.</summary>
    public ContactMap()
    {
        Table("[MyServer].[dbo].[Contact]");
        OptimisticLock.Version();
        DynamicUpdate();
        LazyLoad();

        Id(x=>x.Id)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Column("[Id]")
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Version(x=>x.RecordVersion)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Column("[RecordVersion]")
                .CustomSqlType("timestamp")
                .Not.Nullable()
            .UnsavedValue("null")
            .CustomType("BinaryBlob")
            .Generated.Always();
        Map(x=>x.Active).Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
        // other scalar properties
        Component(x0=>x0.BasicInfo, m0=>
        {
            m0.Map(x1=>x1.FirstName).Column("[BasicInfoFirstName]").Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
            m0.Map(x1=>x1.LastName).Column("[BasicInfoLastName]").Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
            // other scalar properties
        });

        // other relationships

        HasMany(x=>x.Searches)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Fetch.Select()
            .Inverse()
            .LazyLoad()
            .KeyColumns.Add("ContactId");           
    } 
}
```

Search

```
public partial class SearchMap : ClassMap<Search>
{
    public SearchMap()
    {
        Table("[MyServer].[dbo].[Search]");
        OptimisticLock.Version();
        DynamicUpdate();
        LazyLoad();

        Id(x=>x.Id)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Column("[Id]")
            .GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x=>x.Controller).Not.Nullable().Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
        Map(x=>x.Module).Not.Nullable().Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);
        Map(x=>x.Name).Column("[Name]").Not.Nullable().Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore);

        References(x=>x.Contact)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Cascade.All()
            .Fetch.Select()
            .Columns("ContactId");
        HasMany(x=>x.DataFilters)
            .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Fetch.Select()
            .Inverse()
            .LazyLoad()
            .KeyColumns.Add("SearchId");
    } 
}
```

Comment: NHibernate 3.0 had many bugs in the Linq provider. Have you tried 3.1 (or 3.2 Beta2 which was released yesterday)?

Comment: @cremor I've upgraded to 3.1 and the problem persists. If I have time, I'll try 3.2

Comment: it could be the space you are doing concatenation with. just try to get first name and last name separately.

Comment: it also would be helpful to see your mappings.

Comment: And... what exactly is the "strange error"?

Comment: @Daniel I tried removing the space and that was not the problem

Comment: @Stefan The error I'm referring to is the superfluous `. as` in the generated SQL. Of course the exception is that there is an error in statement.

Comment: @Steve: Now I see. I wasn't aware that it generates invalid SQL so didn't know where to look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you map Filters with FetchMode.Join?

By the way, it may be easier to create the `ContactIndexViewModel` in memory, with the trade off that it fetches too many columns from the database. On the other side, `Get` doesn't flush the session, which may be performance relevant.

```
var contact = session.Get<Contact>(10);

return new ContactIndexViewModel
{
     Id = contact.Id,
     Name = contact.BasicInfo.FirstName + " " + contact.BasicInfo.LastName,
     Filters = contact.Filters
};
```

Comment: I changed the Fetch mode to `.Join()`, but that did not fix it. Your suggested solution is the work around I am using. I know `.Get()` will try to use the cache, but I'm unclear if `.Query()` does. Are you saying that it won't?

Comment: @Steve: I mean that `FetchMode.Join` may produce the error, you shouldn't do it. No kind of query ever directly hits the cache. Only `Get` and `Load`, which get the id as argument.

Comment: As @Jamie Ide suggests, I suspect this is a bug. I'll try to put together a repeatable project and contact the NHibernate folks. I'm accepting this answer because it's the workaround that I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping for the table is unusual to me.

```
Table("[MyServer].[dbo].[Contact]");
```

Normally the server name is provided during configuration, the schema is stated separately, and the delimiters ("[...]") are set by NHibernate. I would map it as:

```
Schema("dbo");
Table("Contact");
```

That may be causing a parsing problem leading to the odd select. If that's not it, then I think it's a bug -- NHibernate should never issue a select without a table alias and column name.

Comment: Thanks. It may be strange because I'm using LLBLGen. It's all generated code. I'll manually change the mapping as you suggest and see if that addresses the problem.

Comment: Adding the Schema call did not change the generated SQL.

Comment: Then I think it's a bug. The LINQ provider is notoriously buggy (but much improved). I only use the Criteria API and QueryOver for that reason. I'm surprised LLBGen generates code like that.